# ruby - can you iterate over a set of declared functions with lambda or functors?

Tags: ruby, lambda, functor

in ruby if i have n functions:

```
def a
    puts "a"
end

def b
    puts "b"
end
```

is there any way to do an iteration like

```
[a,b].each do |x|
    puts "running #{x.name}
    run a
end
```

One thought I had was can I register an array of functors or something, or maybe lambda can help?

thanks for any help,
kevin

Comment: If you don't intend to invoke the methods by their name, defining an array of lambdas would be indeed a good alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Call Object#send on an Array of Symbols

In Ruby, the `def` keyword defines an object method rather than a function. The closest Ruby has to functions are blocks, procs, and lambdas, but "functions" aren't really first-class concepts in Ruby.

Methods exist on an object, but if you declare them in the top-level namespace (e.g. outside of a class) then they get attached to a special top-level binding that acts *sort of* like a global namespace. It isn't, really, but it's a useful analogy when trying to reason about Ruby when coming from other languages.

Furthermore, when you define a method Ruby returns a Symbol for that method. You can see this in an interactive REPL like irb when defining the method, since Ruby returns a Symbol when the method is defined. While there are ways to invoke method names as a String, internally Ruby stores method and class names as Symbol objects, so that's what I'm going to demonstrate. For example:

```rb
def a
    puts "a"
end
#=> :a
```

With this knowledge, it's easy to iterate over a group of methods stored as an Array of Symbol objects and invoke each of them with [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Object.html#method-i-send). For example:

```rb
def a
    p "a"
end

def b
    p "b"
end

[:a, :b].each { send _1 }
#=> [:a, :b]
```

While it returns the Symbol for each method, it also prints the character you expect to the terminal:

> "a"
> "b"

Note that #puts always returns nil, so using [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) makes more sense when you want to *return* the values generated by iterating over your collection rather than simply sending them to the terminal. If you'd rather return `[nil, nil]` then go ahead and keep #puts instead.

Also, using #map instead of #each with Kernel#p will return a letter rather than a Symbol for each iteration, so be aware of the difference. It might be confusing to expect one and get the following instead:

```rb
[:a, :b].map { send _1 }
# => ["a", "b"]
```

This is because #each returns the original Array, while #map returns the result of mapping the block over each element. They are quite similar, but the subtle difference can trip you up if you're not careful.

#### Preserving Your Original Semantics

If you really want to keep your original semantics, then just call it this way instead:

```rb
["a", "b"].map do |x|
    puts "running method #{x}"
    send x
end
```

This is less idiomatic, and possibly confusing because you're not really working with characters or String objects but will always get a String whether you use #each or #map this way. Nevertheless, it will print and return:

```rb
running method a
"a"
running method b
"b"
#=> ["a", "b"]
```

as you seem to expect.

Comment: This is just about the best answer I've ever gotten from SO, thank you so much for your help. It answers is exactly what I as asking (without judgment or condescension, which I cannot tell you how much I appreciate).  Thanks again.

Comment: @user1130176 Yes, almost anything that descends from Object or BasicObject, including a Class, Module, or Binding stores it's name as a Symbol in ObjectSpace and responds to #send. There are probably a few exceptions, but for the purposes of identity a Symbol rather than a String is typically used for the internal representation of the name of most Ruby objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambdas:

```
[
  -> () { p "a" },
  -> () { p "b" }
].each do
  |proc|
  proc.()
end
```